# Submitting Open Graph Actions for an iOS app?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-opengraph

For an iOS app that doesn't exist yet in the App Store, what I should write for "Steps to Reproduce Your Action" when I am submitting the actions for the  Facebook Open Graph Api ?

Answer (score 5):

You can submit screenshots of the flow of your app as an acceptable alternative when you have a native mobile app such as this. Specifically, the screenshots should show how the action is triggered within the app and then what the story looks like on a user's Timeline.

Upload the screenshots to some URL and then explain and include the URL with your submission.

Source: spoke to team in Facebook responsible for approving actions.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that, the next problem is that it has been sitting in the "pending" state for over a month now..

Comment: What is your App ID? Approvals are currently taking less than 1 day, so you shouldn't be seeing that if you have properly submitted your actions.